Why Can't I Run Two Separate Tor Browsers with Selenium in Python Simultaneously?
I am trying to run two separate instances of the Tor Browser using Selenium in Python, but in two different scripts. I have set up two fresh Tor Browser installations and modified the torrc file in each installation to use different ports.
Each instance works perfectly fine when run individually. However, when I try to start them simultaneously, the second instance fails with the following error:
"Tor exited during startup. This might be due to an error in your torrc file, a bug in Tor or another program on your system, or faulty hardware. Until you fix the underlying problem and restart Tor, Tor Browser will not start." error
I have a freshly installed Windows 11 system with only Python 3 and AnyDesk installed.
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

tor_path = r'C:\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe'


firefox_options = Options()
firefox_options.binary_location = tor_path


driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=firefox_options)

WebDriverWait(driver, 300).until(
EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="connectButton"]'))
)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, value= '//*[@id="connectButton"]').click()

For the second script, I copied the first one and changed the path to the second Tor installation's firefox.exe.
I made sure that both scripts use different ports by connecting them one after the other and checking if the port is in use. The script that is started second doesn't even try to connect because there are no logs generated.Checked if they use different ports

did you run both at the same time directly in system without using selenium? maybe it is not problem with selenium but tor browser use some element which can't be used by to browsers at the same time.

Yes, when I run them directly in the system without Selenium, the same problem occurs. The first one starts, and I can connect, but the second one gets this error when starting and doesn't even try to connect. The logs are empty.

I wonder if two tor proxies can run at the same time. I have one tor proxy running as daemon on Linux and I can use it with any browser - but when I try to run another tor proxy then it says that tor already running - but I didn't try to use different config

I can run second tor proxy when I change SocksPort ControlPort and DataDirectory. It doesn't allow me to use the same directory by two proxies

I don't know how but I could run two tor-browser but with different profiles and they both could connect to internet. But I can't reproduce it. Second browser always says that it can't run tor-proxy. But I see every tab in browser uses own connection with different IP. And this can be some method if you can switch tabs during work. webdriver.switch_to.window(...)

I figured out how to manually open multiple Tor Browsers on my system by changing the ports in about:config and torrc_default, and setting media.autoplay.default to 0 in the second browser. However, I still have the same issue when trying to open them using Python and Selenium. It does work when I start them using subprocess.run or subprocess.Popen, but I'm not sure how to use it with Selenium.

Selenium may run it without your profile so it may run with default settings. How to load a existing FirefoxProfile through Selenium and Python - Stack Overflow

When add the profile from each tor, both starts without error but when I click conenct the error still comes up in the second script that starts, again no logs and both use different ports. `options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.profile = r"C:\Users\anjoyer\Desktop\All Tors\Tor Browser2\Browser\TorBrowser\Data\Browser\profile.default"
firefox_binary_path = r"C:\Users\anjoyer\Desktop\All Tors\Tor Browser\Browser\firefox.exe"
options.binary_location = firefox_binary_path
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)`

did they use different DataDirectory?

I added, DataDirectory C:\Users\anjoyer\Desktop\All Tors\Tor Browser2\DataDirectory
to the torrc_defaults file. I dont know how to verify wich DataDirectory they use

maybe it will have it when you use url about:about. Or maybe it will be in about:profiles. As I know about:tor shows only page with button to activate tor in browser. In about:config when I search torlaucher then shows control port but I see only some empty option with some name datadir

I looked in about:profiles and they used all the same profile and after that it changed somehow idk but now its working fine

if it will still work then you could check if it work when you use only tor-browser. Maybe it doesn't need other folder with Tor. And if it will work then you could describe it as answer below. It can be useful for other people

I'm not sure what you mean by "Maybe it doesn't need another folder with Tor." You need different Tor installations with different ports and different profiles. The only problem was that the profile didn't change with this Python code alone: options.profile = r"C:\\Users\\anjoyer\\Desktop\\All Tors\\Tor Browser2\\Browser\\TorBrowser\\Data\\Browser\\profile.default" I needed to use about:profiles in the manually opened Tor browser. After that, it changed the profile path.

nevermind, I was thinking like with normal firefox which doesn't run own proxy server but it can uses "external" proxy server to access page - and every profile may have own file prefs.js in which it may keep different settings for proxy. So it allows to run manually two tor-proxy (with different ports) and keep on disk only one firefox but two profiles (which connect with different tor-poxy). But I forgot that `tor-browser runs own tor-proxy so it needs two tor-browsers to run two tor-proxy.
